# How to fix Spring Load Balancing issue with ribbon "Error choosing server for key default"?

Tags: spring-cloud

I have been trying to familiarize myself with spring boot load balancing.
i have a problem when trying to access the services using the load balancer URL.
i get a long stack trace but it from the looks of it it seems to start here

```
2021-05-17 20:44:05.540  WARN 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : LoadBalancer [chatbook]:  Error choosing server for key default
```

my entire code is here https://github.com/wizz269/springLoadBalancing

and here is the stacktrace

```
"

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.3.10.RELEASE)

2021-05-17 20:43:47.834  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] com.demgo.userapp.UserAppApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-05-17 20:43:48.598  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=3629af68-69dc-3f8d-91e5-bea3a5e48117
2021-05-17 20:43:49.006  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2021-05-17 20:43:49.014  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-17 20:43:49.014  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-17 20:43:49.210  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-17 20:43:49.211  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1335 ms
2021-05-17 20:43:49.284  WARN 23156 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2021-05-17 20:43:49.284  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2021-05-17 20:43:49.288  WARN 23156 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2021-05-17 20:43:49.288  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2021-05-17 20:43:49.431  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-05-17 20:43:49.601  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-05-17 20:43:50.294  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2021-05-17 20:43:50.748  INFO 23156 --- [  restartedMain] com.demgo.userapp.UserAppApplication     : Started UserAppApplication in 5.553 seconds (JVM running for 8.061)
2021-05-17 20:44:04.554  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-17 20:44:04.554  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-17 20:44:04.562  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2021-05-17 20:44:05.386  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-chatbook
2021-05-17 20:44:05.388  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: chatbook instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=chatbook,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2021-05-17 20:44:05.397  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2021-05-17 20:44:05.420  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: chatbook.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2021-05-17 20:44:05.516  INFO 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client chatbook initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=chatbook,current list of Servers=[localhost:8084, localhost:8082, localhost:8083],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {unknown=[Zone:unknown;    Instance count:3;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:localhost:8084;    Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:localhost:8082;   Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:localhost:8083;   Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@4f6e06f2
2021-05-17 20:44:05.536  WARN 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule  : No up servers available from load balancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=chatbook,current list of Servers=[localhost:8084, localhost:8082, localhost:8083],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {unknown=[Zone:unknown;   Instance count:3;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:localhost:8084;    Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:localhost:8082;   Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:localhost:8083;   Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EAT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@4f6e06f2
2021-05-17 20:44:05.540  WARN 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : LoadBalancer [chatbook]:  Error choosing server for key default

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:878) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3950) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4935) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerStats.getServerStats(LoadBalancerStats.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerStats.getSingleServerStat(LoadBalancerStats.java:372) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityPredicate.apply(AvailabilityPredicate.java:73) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityPredicate.apply(AvailabilityPredicate.java:35) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.CompositePredicate.apply(CompositePredicate.java:52) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.CompositePredicate.apply(CompositePredicate.java:40) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule.choose(AvailabilityFilteringRule.java:86) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer.chooseServer(BaseLoadBalancer.java:755) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.ZoneAwareLoadBalancer.chooseServer(ZoneAwareLoadBalancer.java:113) [ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.getServer(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:189) [spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:117) [spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) [spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58) [spring-cloud-commons-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:672) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:313) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at com.demgo.userapp.UserAppApplication.invokeChatbook(UserAppApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at 
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_281]

2021-05-17 20:44:05.552 ERROR 23156 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for chatbook] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for chatbook
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:313) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at com.demgo.userapp.UserAppApplication.invokeChatbook(UserAppApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar:5.2.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_281]

2021-05-17 20:44:06.409  INFO 23156 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: chatbook.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
```

**Note : Each service instance i put up on its own works fine, only the load balancing part. will appreciate the assist**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. worked after removing this code

@Bean

```
public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
    return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2705#issuecomment-367824353

worked after deleting this line of code

```
@Bean
    public IRule rule(IClientConfig ribbonClient)
    {
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }
```

still not sure why this worked, i'd appreciate if anyone cares to explain